# How to include hyperlinks to PDF files when exporting LaTeX from org-mode?

Tags: org-export

I am writing an org-mode file with links like `[[./files/article.pdf]]`. If I export this to HTML, it works as expected, creating a blue underlined text hyperlink to the file. But if I export to PDF via LaTeX instead, I get a full-sized image of the first page of the PDF embedded in my document. How to get what I want instead?

Comment: See http://orgmode.org/manual/LaTeX-specific-attributes.html *Images in LaTeX export* section. You will need to give the link a name, as in `[[./files/article.pdf][./files/article.pdf]]`.

Comment: @wvxvw: That's it! Please submit that comment as an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Org will treat links without explicitly specified names as if they were images it needs to embed.

[Manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/LaTeX-specific-attributes.html) mentions this in the section **Images in LaTeX export**.  The way to side-step this, is to give a link a name, for example: `[[./files/article.pdf][./files/article.pdf]]`.

Answer (score 0):

In  Linux Emacs org mode ,this can be achieved using docview links like this

```
[[docview:mypdf::50][mypdf-50]]
```